# MongoDb not getting data while evaluating deep nested queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am designing a complex nested query structure for retrieving data in MongoDb. I am getting successful results when I execute any of the following queries:

```
Query 1

{
    $and : [
        {
            $or : [
                {
                    $and : [
                        {name : /google/i},
                        {date : {$gte : new Date("2002-07-01T00:00:00.000Z")}},
                        {date : {$lt : new Date("2002-07-05T00:00:00.000Z")}}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Query 2

{
    $and : [
        {
            $or : [
                {
                    $and : [
                        {name : /microsoft/i},
                        {date : {$gte : new Date("2002-07-08T00:00:00.000Z")}},
                        {date : {$lt : new Date("2002-07-12T00:00:00.000Z")}}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Query 3

{
    $and : [
        {
            $or : [
                {
                    $and : [
                        {name : /google/i},
                        {date : {$gte : new Date("2002-07-01T00:00:00.000Z")}},
                        {date : {$lt : new Date("2002-07-05T00:00:00.000Z")}}
                    ]
                },
                
                {
                    $and : [
                        {name : /microsoft/i},
                        {date : {$gte : new Date("2002-07-08T00:00:00.000Z")}},
                        {date : {$lt : new Date("2002-07-12T00:00:00.000Z")}}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

All these queries result in successful date retrievation. But when I tried the following query, I'm getting no results. There are zero documents returned:

```
Query 4

{
    $and : [
        {
            $or : [
                {
                    $and : [
                        {name : /google/i},
                        {date : {$gte : new Date("2002-07-01T00:00:00.000Z")}},
                        {date : {$lt : new Date("2002-07-05T00:00:00.000Z")}}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, {
            $or : [
                {
                    $and : [
                        {name : /microsoft/i},
                        {date : {$gte : new Date("2002-07-08T00:00:00.000Z")}},
                        {date : {$lt : new Date("2002-07-12T00:00:00.000Z")}}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't want to rectify Query 4, which I have achieved in Query 3, but I'm unable to find out what's wrong with Query 4. I just want to know the logic behind the failure of Query 4 i.e Why I'm not getting any documents through Query 4.

Comment: In query 4 the `$or` is useless since each `$or` has only one condition. You are basically asking a document which its name is both options...In query 3 this is not the case, the `$or` has two options so you can get each document that matches one of the conditions, not both of them...

Comment: BTW there is no need for the "deepest" `$and` in those queries. By default, you can use several conditions.

Comment: Further to the comments by @nimrodserok , "Query 1" could be simplified to `{name : /google/i, date : {$gte : new Date("2002-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt : new Date("2002-07-05T00:00:00.000Z")}}`.